# Not able to generate the mobx using build runner in flutter

Tags: flutter, build, mobx, build-runner

I am using `mobx` flutter for state management.
but after adding the `mobx` in the project I am unable to build the generated file.
and getting the error

```
Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:
C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\lib\core\uri.dart:3259:39 - Expected an identifier.
[SEVERE] mobx_codegen:mobx_generator on lib/main.dart:
```

mobx file :-

```
import 'package:mobx/mobx.dart';

part 'weather_store.g.dart';

class WeatherStore = _WeatherStore with _$WeatherStore;

abstract class _WeatherStore with Store {
  
}
```

pubspec.yaml:-

```
  dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  mobx: ^0.3.10
  flutter_mobx: ^0.3.4+1
  provider: ^3.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  mobx_codegen: ^0.3.10+1
```

How to solve the problem?

**edit**:- command to build `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who have upgraded to flutter version `1.20.1` or above, make sure you add this line in `pubspec.yaml`.

```
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.14'
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation about why I shoud add this line?

Comment: @LeonardoCosta There some bugs on 1.20.1